# Network doesn't work after upgrading to 13.10

Tags: networking, indicator, 13.10

I upgraded from 13.04 to 13.10, and a number of things stopped working.

Most importantly, I don't have internet access anymore. When I go to the network settings, I receive the following error: `The system network services are not compatible with this version.` The only settings that show up in the network settings are the proxy settings.

I tried `sudo service network-manager start` and `sudo service network-manager restart`, but it told me the service was already running.

In addition, the menu bar is missing all of the indicators (such as keyboard layout, sound, network, clock, and the gear icon). Is this related or a separate issue?

Answer (score -1):

Try running the following command to see if it solves the issue:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Comment: I should have mentioned, but I tried this also and it didn't work.

Comment: okay - did you stop the service as well?

Comment: I experienced the missing indicators as well, but it was fixed after a restart.

Comment: any news on this?